# How someone can execute my unix file after giving permission?

Tags: perl, unix

I have already given permission to execute my perl file to group and others(using chmod 711) but what command line I should give them to execute my file.

can someone please help me with this.?

Thank you.

Comment: `755` if you want group and others to be able to execute your script

Comment: chmod go=rx myfile.pl

Comment: I don't want them to read my file.. I just want them to execute it and see the result..

Answer (score 2):

When someone start such a file, it will actually be read by the perl interpreter program, which means that it must allow read access as well.

Suppose your file is called 'myfile.pl', you can then always start it with

```
perl /path/to/myfile.pl
```

In that case you start the perl interpreter and tell it to read commands from your file.

If your file is readable and executable, and starts with a line like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

then you can start it with

```
/path/to/myfile.pl
```

which, in case the file is in the current directory can be as short as

```
./myfile.pl
```

Comment: In addition, if the file has the correct #! line, it can be placed in some public director like /usr/local/bin, and then just `myfile.pl` should be enough to run it.